# Cannot get value from the HTML tag input type date, Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, binding

Why does the value from input type date html tag is not being applied to the corresponding object setter?

Put it in another words: when I type a date into the following html field:

```
 <form:input path="dateOfBirth" type="date" name="date" id="date" max="09/09/2015"/>
```

and then put a break point at the following method:

`System.out.println(customer.getFirstName());`

and look for the

```
customer.getBirthDate()
```

the latter returns me `null`

Here is the `Customer object`

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column (name = "date_of_birth")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

// all getters/setter are being defined + hashCode()+equals()
}
```

Here is my JSP form:

```
<form:form class="pure-form pure-form-aligned"
           action="/register"
           method="post"
           onsubmit="return validateUserInput();"
           modelAttribute="user">

    <fieldset>
            <%--Date of birth--%>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="date">Date of birth</label>
            <form:input path="dateOfBirth" type="date" name="date" id="date" max="09/09/2015"/>
            <label id="errorDate" style="width: auto"></label>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

And my controller that handles the registration process:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/register")
public class UserRegistrationController {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;


    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        CustomDateEditor editor = new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, editor);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(CustomerTypeEditor.class, new CustomerTypeEditor());
    }


    @ModelAttribute("customertypes")
    public List<CustomerType> customerTypes() {
        return customerService.getCustomerRepository().getCustomerTypes();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayRegistrationForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new Customer());
        return "register";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processUserRegistration(@ModelAttribute Customer customer) {
        System.out.println(customer.toString());
        System.out.println(customer.getFirstName());
        customerRepository.insert(customer);
        return "redirect:/dashboard";
    }
}
```

Just to rephrase the question stated above: when I press submit button, the date value is being inserted into the `customer.setDateOfBirth(Date date)`. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: _the date value is being inserted into the `customer.setDateOfBirth(Date date)`_ Why is that a problem?

Comment: it is the problem because the method `hashCode()` throws Null Pointer exception on the `Date dateOfBirth` field.

Comment: How is `hashCode` related to this issue? What's calling it? Please clarify your question.

Comment: please see the updates

Comment: Why do you give your `form:input` element a `name`? Get rid of that. It will automatically be generated from the `path`.

Comment: I gave it because I am using external CSS framework.

Comment: I don't see how that is relevant either. The `id` should be enough for CSS.

Comment: still though your comment about name doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Open your browser's network console and check what is sent in the POST request. Your example works fine for me (assuming a properly formatted date string is sent).

Comment: Could you specify how do you properly format this date?

Comment: You've set an expected format of `yyyy-MM-dd`, so a date string like `2015-09-13` would be appropriate.

Comment: Please make your comment as an answer to my question. I will accept it. You were right in regards to date formating.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the modelattribute but cant find it getting registered in html web page.Kindly do the same as

@modelAttribute="customer"

Answer (score -1):

You are setting wrong `modelAttribute="user"`, instead of declared `@ModelAttribute Customer customer` in your POST method. Try to set `modelAttribute="customer"`

Comment: Nope, I am setting at Model the instance of the `Customer` under `user` attribute i.e. `model.addAttribute("user", new Customer());` The only thing matters is the type on instance. In my case, it is `Customer`

Comment: Yes, but you are setting "user" for GET method